# Fail To Run JBehave in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jbehave

When I run my first JBehave code in JBoss I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/Transformer
at org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:113)
at org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration.<init>(MostUsefulConfiguration.java:53)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.<init>(Embedder.java:48)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.<init>(Embedder.java:58)
at org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedder.<init>(ConfigurableEmbedder.java:39)
at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.<init>(JUnitStories.java:14)
at de.codecentric.simplejbehave._3_stepsfactory.SimpleJBehave.<init>(SimpleJBehave.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitReportingRunner.<init>(JUnitReportingRunner.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at 

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 32 more
```

I have added commons-logging-1.1.3.jar into my Build Path as some solutions in the Internet but they could not solve my problem.
Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Regards

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` states clearly that it cannot find a class in commons.collections; you should add that library to your build path too. Also, if you are managing dependencies by hand, make sure you add any other required dependency.

Comment: Thank your sir, I have solved the problem by finding the right libraries and add it to my Build Path.